# Windows 11 always try to use DNS setting from a uninstalled network adapter

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dns

I have a laptop which is brought to the office and then back home every day.
When I'm sitting in the office, I use a dock with a wired ethernet connection. I have a manually configured gateway & DNS for that wired connection out of working purpose.
When I'm back home, I use WIFI, and the WIFI relies on the router's DHCP server to distribute configuration, nothing special.

But recently, it starts acting weirdly that the WIFI is also trying to use the manually configured DNS of the wired connection, which results in name resolution failure when I'm connected to home WIFI.

I can confirm that 'Obtain DNS server address automatically' is ticked for the WIFI adapter. But in the details tab, I'm seeing the DNS of my office wired connection. However, since the dock is disconnected, the wired adapter is nowhere to be found.

To resolve this, I have to either manually configure DNS for the WIFI adapter, or, I can remove everything in 'Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces' registry and then reboot. Both sound like temporary walkarounds.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Between the office and home, does the computer sleep, or is it cleanly rebooted?

Comment: I always turn the laptop off when I'm off from work. So yes, it is cleanly rebooted. And further reboot won't resolve the problem.